# json failed in Analytics

Tags: json, google-analytics

Google analytics insight search is not working.
Whenever I search something it says json payload received.
[image: This is the screen of that error]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug with the Google Analytics software (I can confirm this happens with other, unrelated GA accounts) and not a programming problem as described in the help center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/